# mvc3 - return bool from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

***Background***

I have a bool in a view model class. I have an if statement checking to see if the bool is true or false. If false I set the value to true and call a view. In the view I have button that when clicked updates and calls the view again. My problem is that the bool keeps being set to false when the view is loaded. I don't know why this is happening. Is there a way to stop the bool from being changed?

***Attempts***

I'm aware MVC is stateless.

The view I've been given to work with is a .aspx view with the "value" attribute of the input tag already being used. So I'm unable to update the value of the Submit button.

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="bvCalc" />
```

***Question***

In whatever way, I'm looking to persist the state of the bool. I don't know how to do this and I'm unsure as to whether or not the best thing to do at this point would be to

1. use a hidden field in the view
2. build an HTML Helper Extension that will update the bool from true to false
3. return the modified value with the model information being sent back to the controller so I can evaluate the data in the if statement.

Comment: Can you not pass the bool back to your controller via the query string? Pass it in the routevalues of the form when it is submitted. It is in one of the overloads of the @Html.BeginForm() helper method.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but management won't allow us to use a querystring on this project. Needs to be as single page app as possible, thanks again though.

Comment: The you should specify FormMethod.Post, or use session variables for this. Post is probably better so you don't have to mess around with setting and erasing the variable each time.

Comment: Just reread your comment... What does "as single-page app as possible mean"? If you post back to the same controller using a query string and then redirect to the same view, wouldn't that be a single-page app? If you do not want to post back, then you could use an ajax call to post back to the boolean value to your controller and the use a partial view to set your page depending on the controller's response.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I've been trying everything I can to make this work ...no luck so far... regarding managements "single-page-app" comment... just means that the user isn't allowed to see anything* in the url besides the domain name.

Comment: I see. Then you definitely want to post your form. Can you provide your view, controller and model code? But, seriously, the answer given by StanK should do what you are after. How are you setting the boolean value in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way values get from a view to controller is via `ModelBinding`.  If you are not familiar with how this works you might like to Google it to get a better understanding.

As a quick example, lets say the action method in your controller that you want to pass the bool to looks like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
  //.. do something here.
}
```

and your ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{  
   public bool MyBool { get; set; }
   // ...more properties...
}
```

As long as your view has some kind of field (e.g. text box, checkbox, hidden field) with a name that exactly matches the property name (in this case 'MyBool') and a value that will convert to the property (in this example the string 'True' can map to to the boolean `true` value) - `ModelBinding` will be able to populate `model.MyBool` with `true` in your controller action.

If you use the built-in helper methods, you don't need to worry about getting the correct name/value in your field element - MVC will do this for you

e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyBool)`  will render HTML something like

```
<input type="hidden" id="MyBool" name="MyBool" value="True" />
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried the above mentioned method however I'm still running into a problem. Everything seems to run smoothly however I (using your example) "MyBool" is defaulted back from true to false. I'm not concerned in any way (for this particular scenario) with what is rendered in the view ... my concern is ...Once the page is submitted I need to access a value (UNCHANGED by an re-initialization) that was on the submitted page.

Comment: If you can add some code to your question from the controller action(s), and the bit of the view where you are rendering the boolean property, I can probably help.

Comment: This bit of code should work for what you want to do. If the value is reset, then the problem is either that it is not set correctly when you are submitting on the page, or that you are overwriting it in you controller. Possibly if you are recreating your view model... Stepping through the code should allow you to identify where you are going wrong. The main question is, how are you setting the value of MyBool on the page? Because just Html.HiddenFor() will only display the value it has in the model and if that is false, then it will submit a false value.

Comment: You're correct. The view model keeps being reinitialized. Due to my lack of experience I didn't realize until just a few minutes ago that the view's (.aspx) BeginForm(**action**, controller, http-method, id) was able to specify the ActionResult. If I can figure out **how to update the action in BeginForm() *from an ActionResult in the Controller*** I believe I can figure this mess out and finally mark this question as answered.

Comment: Can you please clarify as to what you mean by that? Do you mean you need to set the action to which the form will post back dynamically in the view? if that's the case you can add set a variable called in your view like this for eample @Html.BeginForm(@( MyBool ? "Action1" : "Actions2"), controller, formmethod, routevalues, htmlvalues) etc... You can add the code right in the view, or you can use a string variable in your view model and set the action name in the controller and pass the variable to your form in the action parameter.

Comment: Exactly. BeginForm() defines the ActionResult and I'd like to modify that BeginForm() attribute. But I can't seem to be able to get to BeginForm from my ActionResult in the Controller. I'm not using Razor, I'm using the .aspx engine so I can't use @Html.BeginForm(@MyBool ?...

Comment: Got it to work! And Timmy can walk again! God bless us one and all!

Answer (score 0):

Use bool? In your model. Without it bool will always default to be false.

Comment: Public bool? show { get; set; } //? Null coalescence operator allows nulls instead of default false

Comment: I'm hoping I've missed something. Adding the ? to bool in my ViewModel is throwing an error. However the debugger isn't cathching it and I've received an email (sent when there are these kinds of errors) with the stack trace but there's no indication as to what the problem could be. Does the ? need to be placed in the Model or ..shouldn't the ViewModel suffice?

Comment: With some digging I found that the location and error is as follows: **.aspx(143): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)** Line 143: **<tr id="row" style='<%= Model.Show ? "": "display: none" %>'>**

Comment: You would need to declare "bool?" instead of "bool" in your controller. Or possibly give your controller the view model as a parameter to benefit from automatic binding. Your model might need to have a default constructor declared for that though...

Comment: This works. It just doesn't work for the application I'm working in but you couldn't have known that. I tested the Null-Coalle... in a test project and it works great... I'll coding with that from here on in. Thank you!